# RDD.take does not work

Tags: python, apache-spark, rdd

when I input following command in spark:

```
textFile = sc.textFile("README.md")

textFile.take(3)
```

it will output:

```
[u'# Apache Spark', u'', u'Spark is a fast and general cluster computing system for Big Data. It provides']
```

However, when I want to use `spark-submit` to load a `python` file:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext

logFile = "/home/sydridgm/Downloads/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.4/README.md"
sc = SparkContext("local", "Simple App")
logData = sc.textFile(logFile).cache()

logData.take(3)
```

It will not output anything. I'm a little confused. Can anyone explain it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the shell environment and normal application concerning this point is that the shell always print out on the standard output the result of your command. e.g if you create an RDD you'll see PythonRDD, and when you use take it will print the result of take.

When you submit an application, you'll need to print it out yourself :

```
print(rdd.take(3))
```